# passwordless ssh not working

Tags: ssh, openssh, ssh-agent

I've tried to setup a password-less ssh b/w  `A` to `B` and `B` to `A` as well.
Generated the public and private key using `ssh-keygen -trsa` on both the machines.
Used the `ssh-copy-id` utility to copy the public-keys from `A` to `B` as well as `B` to `A`.

The passwordless ssh works from `A` to `B` but `not` from `B` to `A`.
I've checked the permissions of the ~/ssh/ folder and seems to be normal.

`A's .ssh` folder permissions:

```
-rw-------  1 root root 13530 2011-07-26 23:00 known_hosts
-rw-------  1 root root   403 2011-07-27 00:35 id_rsa.pub
-rw-------  1 root root  1675 2011-07-27 00:35 id_rsa
-rw-------  1 root root   799 2011-07-27 00:37 authorized_keys
drwxrwx--- 70 root root  4096 2011-07-27 00:37 ..
drwx------  2 root root  4096 2011-07-27 00:38 .
```

`B's .ssh` folder permissions:

```
-rw------- 1 root root  884 2011-07-07 13:15 known_hosts
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  396 2011-07-27 00:15 id_rsa.pub
-rw------- 1 root root 1675 2011-07-27 00:15 id_rsa
-rw------- 1 root root 2545 2011-07-27 00:36 authorized_keys
drwxr-xr-x 8 root root 4096 2011-07-06 19:44 ..
drwx------ 2 root root 4096 2011-07-27 00:15 .
```

`A` is an ubuntu 10.04 (OpenSSH_5.3p1 Debian-3ubuntu4, OpenSSL 0.9.8k 25 Mar 2009) `B` is a debian machine (OpenSSH_5.1p1 Debian-5, OpenSSL 0.9.8g 19 Oct 2007)

From `A`:

```
#ssh B
```

works fine.

From `B`:

```
#ssh -vvv A 
...
...
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT received
debug2: key: /root/.ssh/identity ((nil))
debug2: key: /root/.ssh/id_rsa (0x7f1581f23a50)
debug2: key: /root/.ssh/id_dsa ((nil))
debug3: Wrote 64 bytes for a total of 1127
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,password
debug3: start over, passed a different list publickey,password
debug3: preferred gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic,gssapi,publickey,keyboard-interactive,password
debug3: authmethod_lookup publickey
debug3: remaining preferred: keyboard-interactive,password
debug3: authmethod_is_enabled publickey
debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
debug1: Trying private key: /root/.ssh/identity
debug3: no such identity: /root/.ssh/identity
debug1: Offering public key: /root/.ssh/id_rsa
debug3: send_pubkey_test
debug2: we sent a publickey packet, wait for reply
debug3: Wrote 368 bytes for a total of 1495
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,password
debug1: Trying private key: /root/.ssh/id_dsa
debug3: no such identity: /root/.ssh/id_dsa
debug2: we did not send a packet, disable method
debug3: authmethod_lookup password
debug3: remaining preferred: ,password
debug3: authmethod_is_enabled password
debug1: Next authentication method: password
root@192.168.122.1's password:
```

Which essentially means it's not authenticating using the file `/root/id_rsa`. 
I ran the `ssh-add` command in both the machines as well.

The authentication part of `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` file is

```
# Authentication:
LoginGraceTime 120
PermitRootLogin yes
StrictModes yes

RSAAuthentication yes
PubkeyAuthentication yes
#AuthorizedKeysFile     %h/.ssh/authorized_keys

# Don't read the user's ~/.rhosts and ~/.shosts files
```

I'm running out of ideas.
Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: What is the setting of `PermitRootLogin` in `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` on A?

Comment: @taneli: `yes`, otherwise the user won't be prompted for a password.

Comment: In my case  I had to uncomment "IgnoreUserKnownHosts yes" in the file "/etc/ssh/sshd_config" on ubuntu 12.04

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Just make sure that you have followed the following procedure:

**On Machine A**

open a terminal and enter the commands as follows:

```
root@aneesh-pc:~# id
```

Just to make sure that we are root.

If the above command output something like below we are root else switch to root using the `su` command

```
uid=0(root) gid=0(root) groups=0(root)
```

1) Create the keys.

```
ssh-keygen -t rsa
Generating public/private rsa key pair.
Enter file in which to save the key (/root/.ssh/id_rsa): 
Enter passphrase (empty for no passphrase): 
Enter same passphrase again: 
Your identification has been saved in /root/.ssh/id_rsa.
Your public key has been saved in /root/.ssh/id_rsa.pub.
The key fingerprint is:
49:7d:30:7d:67:db:58:51:42:75:78:9c:06:e1:0c:8d root@aneesh-pc
The key's randomart image is:
+--[ RSA 2048]----+
|          ooo+==B|
|         . E=.o+B|
|        . . .+.*o|
|       . . .  ...|
|        S        |
|                 |
|                 |
|                 |
|                 |
+-----------------+
```

I haven't used any passphrase. If you need one you can use it.

2) Copy the public key in to machine B's `.ssh/authorized_keys` file

```
root@aneesh-pc:~# ssh-copy-id -i /root/.ssh/id_rsa.pub root@mylap
root@mylap's password:
```

Now try logging into the machine, with `ssh 'root@mylap'`, and check in:

```
~/.ssh/authorized_keys
```

to make sure we haven't added extra keys that you weren't expecting.

Replace mylap with the hostname or ip of the machine you want to login (i.e. machine B)

3) Login to B without password

```
root@aneesh-pc:~# ssh root@mylap
Warning: Permanently added 'mylap,192.168.1.200' (RSA) to the list of known hosts.
Welcome to Ubuntu 11.04 (GNU/Linux 2.6.38-8-generic x86_64)

 * Documentation:  https://help.ubuntu.com/

Last login: Wed Jul 27 15:23:58 2011 from streaming-desktop.local
aneesh@mylap:~$
```

**On Machine B**

4) Create the keys to login back to Machine A

```
root@mylap:~# ssh-keygen -t rsa
Generating public/private rsa key pair.
Enter file in which to save the key (/root/.ssh/id_rsa): 
Enter passphrase (empty for no passphrase): 
Enter same passphrase again: 
Your identification has been saved in /root/.ssh/id_rsa.
Your public key has been saved in /root/.ssh/id_rsa.pub.
The key fingerprint is:
35:9f:e7:81:ed:02:f9:fd:ad:ef:08:c6:4e:19:76:b1 root@streaming-desktop
The key's randomart image is:
+--[ RSA 2048]----+
|                 |
|                 |
|          o   .  |
|         . + + o |
|        S o * E  |
|           = O . |
|            O +  |
|           + o o.|
|            . o+=|
+-----------------+
```

5) Copy the public key in to machine A's `.ssh/authorized_keys` file

```
root@mylap:~# ssh-copy-id -i /root/.ssh/id_rsa.pub root@aneesh-pc
Warning: Permanently added 'aneesh-pc,192.168.1.20' (RSA) to the list of known hosts.
root@aneesh-pc's password:
```

Now try logging into the machine, with `ssh 'root@aneesh-pc'`, and check in:

```
.ssh/authorized_keys
```

to make sure we haven't added extra keys that you weren't expecting.

6) Login to A without password

```
ssh root@aneesh-pc
Warning: Permanently added 'aneesh-pc,192.168.1.20' (RSA) to the list of known hosts.
Welcome to Ubuntu 11.04 (GNU/Linux 2.6.38-8-generic x86_64)

 * Documentation:  https://help.ubuntu.com/


Last login: Tue Jul 26 18:52:55 2011 from 192.168.1.116
```

If you are able to complete these steps You are done. Now you have two machines with ssh-key (public-key) enabled login.

Comment: did all the 6 steps as specified, verified all the things related till step 5, but somehow step 6 is not working

Comment: Can you provide the output of this command : 'ssh -v root@aneesh-pc'. replace the username and hostname with yours.

Comment: found out the culprit the permissions of the `/root` (770)   `drwxrwx--- 70 root root  4096 2011-07-27 00:37 ..`  was too open. Changed the permissions to  `drwxr-xr-x` and now it's working. Couldn't imagine the fact that parent directory's permission affect the `ssh`.

Comment: @Cuurious Good catch, my home directory had `770` set also, changed to a `750` and all is right with the world :) I always seem to forget that linux prems can work in reverse like that.

Comment: Failure at step 3. _ssh-copy-id_ runs after i enter a password, however I am still unable to login without being prompted for a password, my authorized_keys file contains the text of my .pub, and I am offering the key on login. No avail. Permission on all directories are correct.

Comment: If machine B is a Mac then this doesn't seem to work by default (ssh-copy-id command not found).  Unfortunately I don't have admin privileges (access to the Cellar) on machine B so I can't brew install ssh-copy-id.   I was able to create an authorized_keys file on machine A with the copy/pasted data from id_rsa.pub file from machine B and ..  it worked.

Comment: This guide immediately lost me when it required you to be root. Being root can't possibly be a requirement for using ssh keys, can it?

Answer (score 49):

After [setting up password-less ssh](https://askubuntu.com/a/51942/7567), I was still asked for my user password. Looking at `/var/log/auth.log` on the remote machine pointed out the issue:

```
sshd[4215]: Authentication refused: bad ownership or modes for directory /home/<user>
```

So, make sure to have it right:

```
chmod o-w ~/
chmod 700 ~/.ssh
chmod 600 ~/.ssh/authorized_keys
```

While forbidding other users to write over your `.ssh` folder is obvious, having the same requirement for your home folder was trickier.

Also, check `/etc/ssh/ssd_config` to ensure that `RSAAuthentication` and `PubkeyAuthentication` options aren't disabled. Default is `yes` so that shouldn't be a problem.

Comment: also make sure those folders listed above are owned by the correct user

Comment: I got into this situation by untarring a badly created realtek driver archive. It changed the owner on the directory I was untarring it into.

Comment: Your home folder cannot be writable because if it was, then I could just rename your `~/.ssh` to something else, and then create a new one with my own key in there.

Comment: awesome! hadn't thought about looking in the logs on the host machine. Thanks!

Comment: Fantastic answer, after looking into my log, I had the same issue but with the /root directory. The three chmod steps certainly fixed it. Thanks!

Answer (score 14):

Probably just a higher level permissions problem.  You need to **remove write permissions from group and other to your home directory and .ssh directory.**  To fix these permissions, run `chmod 755 ~ ~/.ssh` or `chmod go-w ~ ~/.ssh`.

If you're still having problems, issue the following grep on your log:

```
sudo egrep -i 'ssh.*LOCAL_USER_NAME' /var/log/secure
```

(replace `LOCAL_USER_NAME` with your local user name...)

That should hopefully tell you more about your problem, assuming sshd authentication information is being logged to the secure log, which is should be by default.  If you see errors that look like this:

> DATE HOSTNAME sshd[1317]: Authentication refused: bad ownership or modes for directory /path/to/some/directory

It's the problem described above and you need to find the directory in question and remove the write permissions from group and other.

As for the reason that you would need to restrict write permissions to your home directory (even though permissions are already restricted on your .ssh and subsequent directories) it will allow other users to rename your .ssh directory and make a new one - although that would be unusable as is (due to wrong permissions) the fix for most users would probably be to change the permissions rather than check the content of the directory...

*TLDNR*:  Allowing write access for group and/or other to your home directory will make ssh force password login.

Answer (score 2):

are you using the root account on each machine? Usually on Ubuntu you would use a user account and give it sudo privileges as required.

If your using a non root user `sudo chown $USER -R ~/.ssh` may fix your problem

Other things to check:

double check that B's `id_rsa.pub` is in A's `authorized_keys`.

check A's `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` contains

```
PermitRootLogin yes
RSAAuthentication yes
PubkeyAuthentication yes
```

Comment: Ya, I've enabled the root account in the Ubuntu machine, hence running as a root user in both the system

Comment: Yeah I figured, added a few other suggestions you may have overlooked. That output is really useless though isn't it, nothing about why rsa wasn't accepted.

Comment: you are true the reason why the rsa key wasn't accepted is the essential element here I guess :). the sshd_config contains the above said elements, I've edited the question to incorporate the contents of the `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` file contents

Answer (score -3):

in /etc/ssh/sshd_config on the target
change

> #### PermitRootLogin no

to

> PermitRootLogin yes

then kill -HUP your sshd PID:

> root@dzone2 # ps -ef|grep ssh
>       root 28075 27576   0   Nov 17 ?           6:11 /usr/lib/ssh/sshd
>
> ```
> root 17708 20618   0 10:09:30 pts/37      0:00 grep ssh root@dzone2 # kill -HUP 28075 root@dzone2 # ps -ef|grep ssh
> root 17861 20618   0 10:09:44 pts/37      0:00 grep ssh
> root 17852 27576   0 10:09:42 ?           0:00 /usr/lib/ssh/sshd
> ```

Comment: This won't help. The problem is that passwordless SSH login (authenticating with an RSA key pair) is not working. The instructions you've provided are for making `root` SSH login work. That's completely unrelated to what this question is about. Furthermore, if the `root` account is enabled (it isn't by default in Ubuntu), enabling `root` SSH logins can be quite dangerous.